# Backgroundfetch for more than 30seconds

Tags: ios, download, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, background-fetch

I'm developing an iOS App, where I have to download multiple zip-Bundles.
To handle the downloads I'm using an internal C++ http-framework.

Is there any posibillity to do an `Background-Fetch` for more than 30sec?

One possibility ist the usage of `NSURLSession` With `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, but the http-framework doesnt use NSURLSession.

Another solution would be this one:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{}
```

But this will only work for 30sec.

But how can I download the Zip-Files with an `Background-Fetch` for more than 30sec?

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the **beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:** or **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:** methods on UIApplication in your didEnterBackground method (and calling **endBackgroundTask** when you finish), but that still won't buy you more about three minutes.

To do it right, though, you really have to use NSURLSession.